# Django HTTPS on EC2 without a domain name?

Tags: django, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have a Django app working on HTTP with an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2. I was hoping to get HTTPS working without a domain name. How would I get a self signed certificate to work with the public IPv4 address assigned to my EC2 instance and then launch the django app on EC2 with HTTPS? Is it even possible?

I have tried making a certificate using openssl and running the django app using django-extensions and Werkzeug using python manage.py runserver_plus but the app crashes on ec2 (works fine locally). I have tried a few other python packages with the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this could help, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-on-centos-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need *some* domain name, as you will probably have a hard time finding any official CA which will sign an *IP address* certificate for you. All public EC2 instances usually get a public DNS name, like `ec2-12-34-56-78.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com`. If you can find a CA which will sign a certificate for this address for you, you could use that. However, you'd need to ensure this address won't change over the lifetime of your server, for which you'd need to get an Elastic IP address at least. You also probably won't be able to use free AWS ACM certificates, as you can't use any of the validation mechanisms it offers, since you don't control the *domain*.

The easiest option for you is probably to set up a [CloudFront CDN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html) in front of your server. That'll give you a domain name like `d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net`, which already comes with its built-in certificate. The backend communication between CloudFront and your EC2 instance can be an unsecured HTTP connection. This'll incur a slight overhead cost, but for low or even medium traffic sites, this is really insignificant. If you set it up well, it can also significantly increase the loading speed of at least static assets of your site, as CDNs do.